# Error 1004 keeps popping out when trying to execute the sort VBA command

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

Part 1:

Please help to advise where did it went wrong. Would like to sort for column E via descending order with header

```
Sub SortRows()

Dim destSht As Worksheet
Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Account Level")

destSht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
Range("E2", destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Sort Key1:=Range("E2"), 
Header:=xlYes, _
Order1:=xlDescending

End Sub
```

Part 2:
How should I input the vba code in a way which it could dynamically filter column C based on descending values?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
destSht.Range("E2", destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp)).Sort Key1:=destSht.Range("E2"), 
Header:=xlYes, _
Order1:=xlDescending
```

Based on latest comments 12-May-2022

```
Sub sortRows()
    With Worksheets("Account Level")
        .sort.SortFields.Clear
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.sort key1:=.Cells(2, 4), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: the code works but how do i sort the entire sheet by column E via descending?

Comment: please remember that I can't _see_ your data, sorting all of it requires knowing where it starts, and where it ends...

Comment: Thanks for helping SpectraInstance. I am not sure how do I insert a screenshot in the comments so I have edited my qns and label it under Part2.

Comment: @Chef, that's the sensible place to put it. Your screenshot doesn't show row numbers, though and, from your original question, it's evident that your data extends beyond column D...if I assume it starts in A1, where does it end?

Comment: the data would start from column A to column I. The range would be from A1 to I745, however the rows would differ every report, thus I would want to code to be dynamic. Therefore column D would be column where I would need the data to be sorted as descending order.

I can select cltr+A and cltr+Shift+L and to do a filter, but it would be nice to have a vba code to have it done

Comment: I've added more code to my answer, based on your clarifying that Ctrl+A does work to select all of your data

Comment: wow appreciate the prompt response. the code really works like a charm. really appreciate the assistance!